# Numbering examples in parallel

Tags: numbering, parallel

In my text I have several examples in parallel columns and I want to number the examples, how can I do it? I'm using the package `parallel` but I might use every package you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `multicol` and `expex` can give you the desired result, if I understand correctly what you need.

In you preamble:

```
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{multicol}
```

And where you have the examples, just do something like this:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\pex
\a <example 1>

\a <example 2>

\a <example 3>

\a <example 4>
\xe
\end{multicols}
```

This will give you two separate columns. You can also use it with `enumerate` or `itemize`.

If you want to force a column break, just add `\vfill\null \columnbreak` wherever you want the break to happen.

I hope this helps.